# ARC Welder Crash upon ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, google-chrome-arc

While testing an android app on Chrome (Canary) I stumbled upon this issue.

I'm trying to ACTION_SEND content (json text file) using

```
String tempFile = <path_to_file>;
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "<app.namespace>", tempFile);
baseIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
baseIntent.setType("application/json");
baseIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, contentUri.getLastPathSegment());
baseIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
baseIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, "Hello!");

startActivityForResult(chooser, 1234);
```

In an actual device this work well, but as a Chrome app it lead to a crash AFTER selecting the "Arc" from the intent chooser.

I cannot get the log to work.

On the Chrome log I found this stack trace:

```
[6128:5632:0806/153905:INFO:CONSOLE(38)] "stack_trace: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at android.os.Process$1.run(Process.java:536)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.os.Process$1.run(Process.java:529)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1320)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5510)
    ...3 more
Caused by android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at android.database.MatrixCursor.get(MatrixCursor.java:66)
    at android.database.MatrixCursor.getString(MatrixCursor.java:254)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
    at org.chromium.arc.helper.SendIntentHandler.getSuggestNameFromUri(SendIntentHandler.java:540)
    at org.chromium.arc.helper.SendIntentHandler.getSuggestName(SendIntentHandler.java:588)
    at org.chromium.arc.helper.SendIntentHandler.saveToExternalFile(SendIntentHandler.java:615)
    at org.chromium.arc.helper.SendIntentHandler.run(SendIntentHandler.java:638)
    at org.chromium.arc.helper.ArcActivity.onCreate(ArcActivity.java:56)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
    ...9 more
", source: chrome-extension://goanhijinjeebfniolhakmhgodjiflod/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_main.min.js (38)
```

But it is not directly related to my code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using `FileProvider` directly, `SendIntentHandler` may be attempting to retrieve a non-existent `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` column. I have [a `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper) that can be used in a subclass of `FileProvider` to help work around this. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) shows it in use.

Comment: @CommonsWare the [LegacyCompatCursorWrapper](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper) worked as expected. Thanks.